# Rename a custom member route named helper in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have routes listed as follows

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :invoices, :only => [:show] do
    get 'submit_invoice', :on => :member
  end
end
```

So the middle route creates a url like `/jobs/:job_id/invoices/:id/submit_invoice` which is exactly what I want.  However rails assigns the name `submit_invoice_job_invoice` to the path which is ugly and horrible to type.

How can I make the name just `submit_invoice` so that I can have `submit_invoice_path` and `submit_invoice_url`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer should be:

```
get "/jobs/:job_id/invoices/:id/submit_invoice" => "invoices#submit_invoice", 
:as => "submit_invoice"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :invoices, :only => [:show] do
    get 'submit_invoice', :on => :member, :as => 'submit_invoice'
  end
end
```

Use `:as => 'routename'` and invoke it as `routename_path`.

:)

Comment: That doesn't provide the result I want as it still appends the nested routing at the end.  For example, if is had `:as => "blah_blah"`, the helper will be named `blah_blah_job_invoice`.